# Rspec it block inside shared context causes an 'unable to find matching line from backtrace' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have seen similar threads on SO, but have been unsuccessful with their suggestions. All I want to test is whether the following method logs a deprecation warning, however, I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work properly.  `make_request` is another method inside the same class (Client).

Method:

```
def get_person(pop_id, person_id)
  path = 'path_url'

  data_hash = make_request(path, person_id: person_id, pop_id: pop_id)
  Rails.logger.warn '#get_person is deprecated.'
  Service::Person.deserialize(data_hash)
end
```

Test Code:

```
...
context 'when making a request'
    include_context 'making a GET'
    describe '#get_person' do
        let(:client) { described_class.new }
        let(:path) { 'some/path' }
        let(:person_id) { 'person-1' }
        let(:pop_id) { 'population-1' }

        it_behaves_like 'a client'

        context 'when the service request returns' do
          let(:mock_response) { {} }

          before do
            allow(client).to receive(:make_request)
             .with(path, person_id: person_id, pop_id: pop_id)
             .and_return(mock_response)
          end

          it 'logs a deprecation warning' do
            expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:warn)
            client.get_person(population_id, person_id)
          end
        end
    end

    ...
end
```

Running the above test gives me a 
`Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace` error in the console.  I'm not even sure what this cryptic message means.  Even putting an empty it block inside the test description causes this error.  The easy solution would be to move this log test outside of the shared context in its own description, but I would like to have just one describe for each function.  Any help working out this test properly would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: try commenting out stuff to see what the line causing the error is

Comment: @maxpleaner Did some testing and updated the question to reflect what I found.  Basically any sort of it block inside of a shared context causes this error.